# Django production issue with ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I moved code from my dev machine to production for the first time and what **works on my machine** ™ is breaking on the live server. What happens is that when I go retrieve the `Game` instance from `gamedb` trying to get `game.players[0]` in the `current_player` view it tells me `game` is `None`. What's strange though is that if I take the ajax url and paste it in the browser the view returns correctly the json it's supposed to. So calling the following:

```
http://example.com/current_player/47dd98e9c6aa06ab646d39e516ce54d6db70c2bb/
```

Gives the following correct output:

```
["Eve", "e4a70a8e99a4efdfd9331d180cd51798b2291a46"]
```

I suspect there's something wrong in the way I setup my ajax call, but can't spot anything wrong.

This is my whole call-stack:

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^start/$', 'briscola.views.play')
url(r'^current_player/([a-z0-9]{40})/$', 'briscola.views.current_player')
```

**game.js**

```
function currentPlayer(game_uid) {

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/current_player/' + game_uid + '/',
    success: function(play_data) {

      var player_name = play_data[0];
      console.log('current player ' + player_name);

    }

  });
}
```

**views.py**

```
def start(request):

    p1 = Player('Eve')
    p2 = Player('Adam')

    game = Game([p1, p2])
    gamesdb.set(game.uid, game)

    players = game.players

    output = dict(players=players)

    return render_to_response('index.html', output)

@csrf_exempt
def current_player(request, game_uid):

    game = gamesdb.get(game_uid)

    current_player = game.players[0] 
    play_data = simplejson.dumps([current_player.name, current_player.uid])

    return HttpResponse(play_data, mimetype='application/json')
```

Comment: If you use chrome/firebug dev tools, what's the network request that's actually getting issued?

Comment: Hi Jure, on Chrome I can see the right url being called (such as http://example.com/current_player/47dd98e9c6aa06ab646d39e516ce54d6db70c2bb/) and if I double click on it on the Network tab, it executes the view correctly and returns the expected json.

Comment: You can log the url property of the ajax call and verify it. Just in case..

Comment: What happens if you add: dataType: 'json' in your ajax code?

Answer (score 1):

You need pass to `$.ajax` additional param: `dataType: "json"`. Or use `$.getJSON` wrapper for `$.ajax` that will prepare necessary params for you.

Comment: Alexey this helped a bit but still didn't solve the problem. It's becoming a little difficult to reproduce but the dataType param allowed me to go to move to next call (although not consistently all the time). Why would the dataType param not be necessary on the Django dev server?

Comment: @L.DeLeo It's strange. This param is required for json output in any case. Can you pls show results for `console.log(play_data)`?

Comment: It's failing with a 500 error now when called from ajax. But when I call the url directly from the browser it returns an array such as
["Eve", "f8cd882346e89f142e091877f62c8d31dfc63d57"] that is a Python list serialized with simplejson

Comment: @L.DeLeo And what do you see in stack traces?

Comment: Request URL: http://example.com/current_player/d39d291539ac4ffae4dc5abf131cb9f5d6e669f1/

Traceback:
File "/home/examp/webapps/example/lib/python2.7/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  77.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/examp/webapps/example/foo/bar/views.py" in current_player
  56.     current_player = game.players[0] 

Exception Type: AttributeError at /current_player/d39d291539ac4ffae4dc5abf131cb9f5d6e669f1/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'players'

Comment: @L.DeLeo This means that you have to look at `game = Game([p1, p2])` - something goes wrong just here :) Or here `gamesdb.set(game.uid, game)`...

Comment: I thought of that but calling the url directly (not from ajax but from the browser) returns the correct result which are fished out of gamesdb

Comment: @L.DeLeo Try to logging `game_uid` value in `current_player(request, game_uid)` call in both cases. And show pls relative URL pattern.

Comment: Looks like there's been some encoding issue but even this I cannot repro all the time. I had to add this line to the current_player view     game_uid = game_uid.encode('ascii', 'ignore') and it brought me one step further but also inconsistently.